# Angular with API Gateway, getting on POST request has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, api, http, cors, api-gateway

I have an Angular app which uses an API from AWS API Gateway. I can do a GET request for one endpoint and get the necessary data, however when I do a POST request I get the following error message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://46pkjw13ag.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/plateListing' from origin 'https://1guv.github.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Angular app > I have tried various header settings but I still get the same error

```
headerDict = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'x-api-key': environment.awsConfig.xApiKey
  };

  requestOptionsGet = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders(this.headerDict),
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors',
  };

  requestOptionsPost = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders(this.headerDict),
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
  };

getPlates() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.awsUrl} + 'platelistings'`, this.requestOptionsGet);
  }

createPlate(newPlate: any) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.awsUrl}plateListing`, newPlate, this.requestOptionsPost);
  }
```

AWS API Gateway > I have checked the Lambda function code for this endpoint and it does supposedly should return a 201 response, but it just doesn't work. See below code:

```
#POST PLATE LISTING
def postPlateListing(requestBody):
    try:
        table_listing.put_item(Item = requestBody)
        body = {
            'Operation': 'SAVE',
            'Message': 'SUCCESS',
            'Item': requestBody
        }
        return buildResponse(201, body)
    except:
        logger.exception('an error occured with post request, please contact your admin')

def buildResponse(statusCode, body = None):
    response = {
        'statusCode': statusCode,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        }
    }
    if body is not None:
        response['body'] = json.dumps(body, cls = CustomEncorder)
    return response
```

I have also added CORS via the API Gateway > Resources > Actions > Enable CORS but everything I try is not working at all.

[API Gateway CORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vfEF.png)

I have been trying to find a solution off and on for a week but need help now.. I know its going to be something small.

Also all endpoints work using Postman, however as I understand it POSTMAN bypasses CORS so this is a setting/configuration somewhere but not sure where or how to diagnose. Please help.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-*` are response headers; they don't belong in a request.

Comment: this is a problem with your API gateway, most assuredly not a problem with your Angular application. You might want to ask another question about how to configure the AWS gateway to enable a Cross-Origin request. As @jub0bs said, those Access-Control headers are ones that the server needs to send back in the response, not headers that you send in the request.

Comment: I have removed the `Access-Control-Allow-*` from the headers but still get the same issue. In the API Gateway, to enable CORS, you have to do the following API Gateway > Resources > Actions > Enable CORS which I have for each endpoint but I cant seem to resolve the issue.